# Impact of reduction on Dynamic energy and dynamic power in microprocessors

Tags: power, clock, microprocessor, energy, clock-speed

A microprocessor has been designed to have a dynamic switch which reduces power consumption when the loading reduces. Assuming a reduction of 20% in voltage reduces clock frequency by 20%. Calculate the impact of this reduction on dynamic energy and power.
Help please

Comment: show some of your own work, as a hint I can say you should define energy and power(probably an integral) and redefine them based on the new terms you were given and you will be able to calculate the reduction they meniton

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions without any own attempt at solving them give no clue where the asker is stuck. They are hence both *too broad* to be answerable, and *do not actually reflect any question of the asker themself* – making them essentially a non-question.

Comment: (whoever upvoted this question: I'd invite you to take part in the [Meta.SE discussion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7282/how-do-we-stop-the-upvoting-of-incomplete-questions-and-unattempted-homework) on how to and whether to avoid that)